# Trying to read (not write to) a volume fails because of write-protection. What gives?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, write-protect

So I have this USB stick with the write-protect switch on and some data that I need to read. That's fine, I don't want to write to it anyway. I just want to read the data on it.

Trying to access the drive, whether in Explorer or CMD, gives me the error, "The media is write protected." But all I'm trying to do is read it.

I can't even Google the problem because all hits assume I'm trying to write to it.

Comment: It's probably trying to modify the "last accessed" time...

Comment: Or is encrypted. Some encryptio schemes require write access to files or the volume.